# How to run Jade agents in two containers (from two consoles)

Tags: java, containers, agents-jade

I'm new in Jade and study [Jade Primer](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer4.html#6). I'm using the latest version Jade v4.2.
I'm trying to set up two behaviours, each coded to receive messages. I should run them in two separated windows, but it doesn't work for me.

I'm using Eclipse on WinXp. I have entered classpath to Jade

```
c:\jade\lib\jade.jar;C:\jade\lib\commons-codec\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

and to folder containing my projects

```
C:\Users\me\workspace\jadeProject\src
```

There is folder **primer4** (package added to Java code), where I put my Java files.
I compiled Java files by **javac** from console.

Then I tried to run from the console (from **primar4** folder):

```
%java jade.Boot -agents a1:primer4.Responder;a2:primer4.Responder
```

The First command is working. Then I run second console window and put:

`%java jade.Boot -container main:primer4.Template`

```
INFO: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
pač 19, 2012 4:35:57 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl startBootstrapAgents
SEVERE: Cannot create agent main: Class primer4.Template for agent ( agent identifier 

:name main@10.0.2.15:1099/JADE ) not found [nested java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: primer4.Template]
pač 19, 2012 4:35:57 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFO: Agent container Container-2@10.0.2.15 is ready.
```

I got this error, can somebody tell me:

1. How can I fix it?
2. Is possible to run agents in two containers from one line in console (in one console, the same time)?

Comment: How can I create the agent and add them dynamically to the main-container? I can add agent dynamically but per agent it creates a new container. But I want to create all of them in one container.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `-agents` option in the second command:

```java
java jade.Boot -container -agents main:primer4.Template
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by the Classpath problem. So please make sure the directory which is having your .class files in the classpath.

you can create one agent per container by the

`-container` option.

or you can create the agents by

```
jade.core.Runtime runtime = jade.core.Runtime.instance();

jade.wrapper.AgentContainer home = runtime.createAgentContainer(new ProfileImpl());

home.createNewAgent(getName(), Agent.class.getName(), args);
```

Like this you can create the agents and add dynamically.

Comment: Hello, where should you put the code to create a container?
Thanks.

Comment: How can I create the agent and add them dynamically to the main-container? I can add agent dynamically but per agent it creates a new container. But I want to create all of them in one container.